fcm local notification open status bar only
If you set the channel to "high_importance_channel"
The pop-up does not appear, but only in the status bar.
Please help me
Here is my code:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <application
        android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"
        android:label="choosing"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:showWhenLocked="true"
            android:turnScreenOn="true">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" android:exported="false" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="high_importance_channel" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </application>
    <!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
         https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility and
         https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

         In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>


import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

class FirebaseApi {
  final _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  final _androidChannel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel',
    'High Importance Notifications',
    description: 'This channel is used for notification',
    //importance: Importance.max
  );

  final _localNotifications = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();



  Future<void> initNotifications() async {
    await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();

    final FCMToken = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();

    print('mattabu: Token: $FCMToken');

    initPushNotifications();
    initLocalNotification();
    showTestNotification();
  }

  Future<void> showTestNotification() async {
    const androidDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'test_channel_id',
      'Test Channel',
      channelDescription: 'This is a test notification',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      playSound: true,
      fullScreenIntent: true,
    );

    const notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(android: androidDetails);

    await _localNotifications.show(
      0,
      'Test Title',
      'Test Body',
      notificationDetails,
      payload: 'Test Payload',
    );
  }

  Future initLocalNotification() async {
    const android = AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_launcher');
    const settings = InitializationSettings(android: android);

    await _localNotifications.initialize(settings);

    final platform = _localNotifications.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
        AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>();
    await platform?.createNotificationChannel(_androidChannel);
  }

  void handleMessage(RemoteMessage? message) {
    if (message == null) return;
    print('mattabu: $message');
  }

  Future initPushNotifications() async {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then(handleMessage);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(handleMessage);

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
      final notification = message.notification;
      if (notification == null) return;
      print("id ${_androidChannel.id}");
      _localNotifications.show(
        notification.hashCode,
        notification.title,
        notification.body,
        NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            _androidChannel.id,
            _androidChannel.name,
            channelDescription: _androidChannel.description,
            //icon: '@drawable/ic_launcher', 
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.high,
            playSound: true,
            fullScreenIntent: true,
          ),
        ),
        payload: jsonEncode(message.toMap()),
      );
    });
  }
}

tried to pop up local notification but opened status bar only
